# Strip_tags PHP - Get structure back

Tags: php, html

When Im running this script i can't get the structure back of the HTML-page.
It's just a lot of text with no br or new lines.

Here's the script:

```html
<?php


$page = strip_tags(file_get_contents('http://stats.swehockey.se/Teams/Info/TeamRoster/5467#G%C3%96T'));

file_put_contents('teams.txt', $page);

$start = 677; 
$end = 840;   

$lines = file('teams.txt'); 
for ($i = $start; $i <= $end && $i < count($lines); $i++) {
    echo $lines[$i];
}

?>
```

I want to get the structure back so i can put the content into a mySQL database.

Comment: If you want the original structure back, save the original structure *before* calling `strip_tags()`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you are using strip_tags() after getting the content, here is what the documentation says:

> strip_tags — Strip HTML and PHP tags from a string. [Learn more about strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

It's normal that you get this result. To get all the HTML you have to delete it:

```
$page = file_get_contents('http://stats.swehockey.se/Teams/Info/TeamRoster/5467#G%C3%96T');
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
<?php
$page = file_get_contents('http://stats.swehockey.se/Teams/Info/TeamRoster/5467#G%C3%96T');
file_put_contents('teams.txt', $page);
$start = 677; 
$end   = 840;   
$lines = file('teams.txt'); 
for ($i = $start; $i <= $end && $i < count($lines); $i++) {
    echo $lines[$i];
}
?>
```